# Nuxt creating micro-apps which share the app state

Tags: authentication, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm using `nuxt` to create interface of my app and I'm facing a wall here. I want to structure my nuxt app basically in two micro apps like so:

```
|--- nuxt.config.js
|--- admin
|------ components
|------ pages
|------ middleware
|--- frontend
|------ components
|------ pages
|------ middleware
```

The reason for creating two micro apps instead of two standalone nuxt apps is that I want to share the `vuex` state between both apps, and in vuex state I'm basically interested in knowing user logged-in state within both micro apps (i cannot do it if I separate the apps completely).

I'm usin nuxt official `auth` module to handle user authentication, which saves the user logged-in state in vuex store.

The most nearest solution I came up with is to use the `srcDir` in `nuxt.config.js` file with different values like so:

```
export default {
  srcDir: 'admin/'
}
```

and change it to following via environment variable:

```
export default {
  srcDir: 'frontend/'
}
```

but it has the same shortcoming, that is, it does not share the app state (e.g. user logged-in state) between both micro apps.

Any solution how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to solve this problem in page level like this structure !

```
|--- nuxt.config.js 
|----components
|----pages
|------- admin
|------- frontend   
|----middleware
```

and in auth redirect user to related pages and route

Comment: I don't think we can have these folders (e.g. components, middleware) in the `pages` folder. I can however create two subfolders named `admin` and `frontend` in each root folder (e.g. components, middleware, plugins).

This has two disadvantages though, it makes the code more complex. The other issue, and more importantly in my case, is that we cannot use a reverse-proxy to serve pages from two different folders at two different domain. For example:

`admin.example.com` to serves pages from `/pages/admin/`
`*.example.com` to serves pages from `/pages/frontend/`

Comment: I edit it to correct one ! please check it now please